# How to work with fonts and icons in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

I needed to create webpack config for project where I use reactjs,semantic-ui-react and nucleo icons. It build almost everything except fonts and icons. I don't quite understand how to build them and nucleo icons dont display in project after build.My config:

```
const path      = require('path');
const webpack   = require('webpack');

const autoprefixer            = require('autoprefixer');
const ExtractTextPlugin       = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const ASSETS_PATH             = './assets';
const BUILD_DIR               = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');

var webpack_config = {

    context: path.resolve(__dirname, ASSETS_PATH),

    entry: {
        main           : [
                            "react",
                            "react-dom",
                            "react-props",
                            "redux",
                            "react-redux",
                            "redux-thunk"
                        ],
        module  : "./js/module/index.jsx",
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].min.js',
        path: BUILD_DIR + '/js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [' ','.js', '.jsx', 'css']
    },

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                loader : 'babel-loader?compact=true&comments=true&minified=true',
                query: {
                    presets:[
                        'es2015',
                        'react',
                        'stage-1'
                    ]
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=../css/fonts/[name].[ext]',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=../css/images/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            }
        ]
    },


    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production')
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "../css/style.min.css",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            assetNameRegExp: /\.min\.css$/g,
            cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
            cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } },
            canPrint: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["main"]
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize  : true,
            sourceMap : false,
            beautify  : false,
            comments  : false,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = webpack_config;
```

So as a result I get js bundles in map 'js', I get css bundle style.min.css in css map. There also webpack creates images map, and puts jpg,png,svg. But font files(eot,ttf etc) he puts in js map with long names. How should I refactor my config in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this problem with such loader structure(maybe will be usefull for somebody):

```
{
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2?)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                    , options: {
                        name: '../css/fonts/[name]-[hash:8].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            },
```